# skip before action in child controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have an application controller where I'm handling some authentication

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  before_action :prep_data
  def prep_data
   # code...
   # authenticate
  end
end
```

and I have a controller that inherits from this one

```
class OtherController < ApplicationController
  def custom_action_method
  end
end
```

can I skip the `before_action` hook for the `OtherController` for a custom action method `custom_action_method`

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I found the answer, this is the syntax

```
class OtherController < ApplicationController
  skip_before_action :prep_data, only: [:custom_action_method]

  def custom_action_method
  end
end
```